# Incorrect review and ban for two days

Tags: discussion, support, triage

I reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16037895) as "requires editing" and the audit failed because it was spam.

I had spent **significant time understanding the quality of the post** and then made my decision.

I opened the link he/she attached and it seemed to me like a datasheet. I didn't find anything wrong about that because the datasheet seemed related to his/her question (microchip name was same about the microchip mentioned in the question).

Then I looked for comments. I saw this:

> Flagged as spam because of the link. The user tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641633/the-troubles-about-battery-and-light) before (10k only)

I have only 763 reputation points and couldn't see the content. I couldn't make my decision based on another's comment which I couldn't verify. Accusing a user of posting spam is a big step IMHO and the post was obviously not OK. So, I thought about clicking `requires editing` (okey, this requires some explanation. Why was the question not OK? Because the OP didn't mention what the actual problem is he/she facing (just mentioned not working) and from the review queue top section: "(click) *Requires editing for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable*". So, clicking it does not mean that editing has to be done by a random person. It can also mean that it needs to be edited by the author too. In this case, I meant that the author needs to edit the question).

I think the audit question was too tricky for me to decide. Ans this makes me feel bad because I have just received my 1k review badge (Steward) hours ago and as far as I can remember, I have never failed an audit in the past.

However, I have only one question regarding this incident:

**Should reviewers refrain from reviewing a question if he/she couldn't understand the code (actual or gibberish) posted in the question?** Frankly, I didn't understand the code he/she posted in the question. I couldn't differentiate if this is actual code or gibberish. I have always looked for other things like:

- If the question is too broad
- If OP has shown some code he/she tried
- If it's related to programming
- If the Markdown/formatting is OK
- etc.

Comment: If you don't understand the code at all, it's best to use "Skip".

Comment: *"the post was obviously not OK. So, I thought about clicking requires editing"* And what should a random person edit to make that post "ok"?

Comment: @Tom: given a bit of copy editing it would have been a so-so question.

Comment: FWIW the "this" link's content is archived at https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/59794

Comment: We did some research and it seems that the user is indeed a spammer, just a very clever one. At one point he posted a chunk of code on dsp.stackexchange, where the code was highly relevant to the target CPU (a Texas DSP). But it turned out it was just a copy/paste from Texas code examples and not at all written by him. I would suspect that this particular code is also stolen from somewhere. At any rate, a very bad post for review audits.

Comment: Same code here: http://www.51hei.com/mcu/4211.html.

Comment: I spent time answering a new question correctly that was marked by a reviewer as a duplicate. The reviewer did not understand the C code and I don't believe it was a duplicate question. What can I do in this situation? I now feel like it is waste of time for me to try to answer new questions.

Comment: @DanRandolph I don't think this is a one person job. I don't know what is the actual procedure to close a question as a duplicate (I don't have that privilege, it requires 3000 rep I think) but I know that it requires a vote. [It takes 5 close votes to reach the closing threshold](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). So, If the question is closed as a duplicate, then I think there is a little chance of mistake.

Comment: @Tom from the review queue top section: `Requires Editing for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable`. You have missed **by the author** part. eg: in the "question" OP didn't mention what actual problem is he/she facing(just mentioned not working). So, clicking requires editing means it needs to be edited by the author too, not always by a random person. :)

Comment: No, you have missed that this description is wrong since the first day that queue exists (read for example this: [Triage Review Queue - Inconsistent guidelines for "Requires Editing"?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319128)). There are several requests to fix that already, but StackExchange doesn't seem to care. So, if only OP can fix a question (for example because crucial information are missing), then use "unsalvageable".

Comment: @Tom Thank you! I didn't know that. Good to know.

Comment: If you like to read some of the discussions about that on meta, then search for "triage" or "requires editing". But it is a bit sad, that nothing has changed, yet :/ (about the "requires editing" description).

Comment: @Tom: I wouldn't say *nothing* has changed; there's now a queue header link to the Triage FAQ, which goes to considerable trouble to eliminate this misconception, and has gotten a lot of hits since the linking.

Comment: @NathanTuggy And even Shog9 guesses that this link will be rarely used (I guess so, too). So it doesn't make sense to keep showing wrong/ambiguous information first and hide the correct information in a link.

Comment: @Tom: I still think the queue guidance should be fixed, sure, but I've seen a lot of upvotes and views since the post was linked. It's clearly been quite a bit more visible because of that.

Comment: That's why I think the whole review queue thing is not designed very well. Not only that one get lots of extra work w/o any rewards worth mentioning, you also earn some extra punishment whenever you fail one of these audits (chances are pretty high if you review long enough). Not very motivating ...

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I've cleared the spam flags on the posts: that post was not spam. It won't be used as an audit anymore.

I've lifted your review ban; your most recent set reviews all look reasonable.

Note that you can always *skip* a post if you don't feel comfortable understanding all of it.

Personally, I'd have picked the same option here; there is a code attempt there, and there is a link to the embedded system documentation, but a copy-edit and formatting clean-up is indeed needed. The MCVE is a little lacking (what is the expected outcome, and what happens instead?) but there is a good-faith attempt there.

---

I spoke with some of the spam flaggers and there is an issue with the kynix.com domain being promoted in spam posts over on other sites in the Stack Exchange network (mostly Electrical Engineering and Mechanics; see https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?body=kynix.com).

However, from *just this one post* I am not convinced that this user is part of the spam ring; the question looks genuine to me and links to *PDF documentation*, not to a page where you can buy the chip. If this really was spam, then all I can do is point to https://xkcd.com/810/

Further review does show that they posted 'template questions', where a few words are changed and the link to the product changes, on different sites, which does make the account very suspicious. I've nuked the account for that reason, but the post itself made a terrible audit.

Comment: wow, I never thought I'd live to see a valid use of XKCD 810

Comment: @Kos, what looks like trolling in the eyes of one (_what is best, iOS or Android?_), can be very legitimate matter in the eyes of other. Similarly, spam can be valuable and constructive in the eyes of some people.

Comment: Indeed, @Cœur. Just the other day, I was wondering if there was some way to make certain body parts larger, and then by an amazing coincidence, I got a helpful email describing just such a product!

Comment: @CodyGray you got that email about discounted Magnifying Glasses as well, hey? :)

Comment: Tangentially, here is a related discussion from the SOCVR chat room. The final consensus seems to be that Kynix is a spam outfit after all. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/conversation/kynix-com-investigation